# create folder based on text in csv using c#

Tags: c#, directory

I am newbie and  developing an  windows application where I have a csv file when I upload that  csv file  it should create new folders with that name  and then the images with that folder name   should be copied into the folder.I am stuck with this  and have  no idea how to do that.

```
**csv file**-- folders to be created with these names according to csv file.
LC53NYN
PJ55BCX
L0O2O
WJ13XLL
```

**Images to be copied**

code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Create new folder in C:\ volume.
    //
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\LC53NYN");
```

Comment: Images with that folder-name? Can you explain your requirement more clearly?

Comment: Are you trying to create directories based on text in a CSV file and then copy files into that directory?  We need to see exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yes create folder based  on text in csv adn copy those images which has same folder name images to them

Comment: @preethi: so you have **one** csv-file where each entry is separated by what delimiter? Where are the images?

Comment: What images?  That is what is unclear about this question...  You can't have images in a CSV file so you are missing alot of information in your question.

Comment: I have images in  different folder  with same name as of the text in csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("YourCSV.csv");
```

Will give you all the lines within the given file.
As long as you only have one column in that file it will work.
If you extend the columns you have to get real CSV Parsing.

Then you can iterate over the lines using

```
foreach(string line in lines)
{
}
```

Within that block you can create the folder and move the image

```
// Creates a folder like "C:\MyFolders\LC53NYN\"
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\MyFolders\" + line);

// Moves the image (eg. "C:\MyImages\LC42NYN.png") to the created folder
File.Move(@"C:\MyImages\" + line + ".png", @"C:\MyFolders\" + line);
```

But you have to stick it together yourself.
Also - the creating and moving part could be done better.
There's space for you to extend it.

**EDIT:**

As a tipp, based on the comment of Tim, you could do something like

```
// Get directory path
string directory = Path.Combine(@"C:\MyFolders", line);
```

To get the directory name first. And use this with the other actions like:

```
// Creates a folder like "C:\MyFolders\LC53NYN\"
Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

// Moves the image (eg. named "LC42NYN.png") to the created folder
File.Move(@"C:\MyImages\" + line + ".png", directory);
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you have the Image in a Folder named the same as the Image use:

```
// Get the source path as C:\MyImages\[Code]\[Code].png
string sourcePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\MyImages\", line, line + ".png");
```

And then move using

```
// Move it
File.Move(sourcePath, directory);
```

Comment: Side-note: instead of `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\MyFolders\" + line);` i would use `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine("C:\\", line));`.

Comment: I would too but I wanted to keep it as simple and fast as possible. Due to the OP could probably get frustrated using even more unknown methods.

Comment: The perfect time to learn these unknown methods. Learning useful yet unknwon methods should not be frustating for a "newbie". If you start using the wrong method you often keep using it.